# Correct way for positioning seperate divs on top of each other?

Tags: html, css, positioning

I am trying to transform this:

http://jsfiddle.net/pljehyun/jqUg3/

into this:

[image]

(this question's main concern is the positioning of the divs)

So far, I have the individual elements down and have run into a some problems:

An answerer to a similar question said that I need to absolute position the hovering divs, but I am also planning on changing the opacity of the 'outer' div. If I nested div's, this would cause the form's input fields to become translucent as well because it is the child.

How should I layer two seperate div's?

Comment: ,do you want us to help you transform your effort into the screenshot you just showed.

Comment: the minimum I'm asking is how to get that form field and "sign in" over the grey box in a robust/scalable way. anything more is icing on the cake.

Comment: why dont you put your input in the gray box rather than doing what you have done.

Comment: Yah, that's what I was thinking too, but lowering the opacity of the gray box also messed with the input fields.That's the main reason I have it set up the way it is now.

Comment: you mean lowering the opacity , you lose the effects you have set on hover of your input right.That can be solved , but proper alignment is must.

Comment: sorry, I wasn't clear about that. not that the input:hover is affected, more so the entire text field itself lowers opacity as well. I would like the gray box to be translucent and the text field opaque. is there no other way to align the divs other than nesting them?

Comment: ya I noiced that , you dont want to lose that effect , and you also want the opacity of the outer div to be the same , right?

Comment: yes, something along those lines.

Comment: why dont you use some background image.Or else the opacity of the .box is causing the effect of input to dissappear.

Comment: see this begin, [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jqUg3/1/)

Comment: I think I see where you are going with this, thanks. Is there a way to keep them linked together position wise or are they two independent floating blocks? I am asking b/c this sign in form will be in the middle of the web page.

Comment: you can put it all into div with relative position and margin auto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see this updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jqUg3/1/) , i will edit my answer to put code later

Comment: i ended up using nested divs like you guys recommended in the beginning because of convenience, but I appreciate this answer for sticking to the original goal even if it wasn't the most complete. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to stick to your HTML or can you change it?

You should def. make sure to at least use correct HTML (see the `span` tag that never gets closed).

I am not sure if this is what you try to achieve, but it seems to be a much simpler way to get the result that looks like your picture:

http://jsfiddle.net/jqUg3/6/

Edit: Also added an example that is styled +/- like your picture:

http://jsfiddle.net/jqUg3/8/

Comment: thanks, the nested approach is what I ended up using, but khaled_webdev's answer stuck to the original point which was positioning two independent, none-nested divs.